# Installation guide for Python 3.7 for Windows 11

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

How can I install Python 3.7 for my 64-bit Windows 11 Home Edition? I found that status of Python 3.7 is "End of Life". Link [here](https://devguide.python.org/versions/#versions)

I am required to install it because one of my projects has software requirements like

```
Python 3.7 
Keras 2.2.4. 
tqdm
codecs
hard-bert = 0.80.0
tensorflow-gpu = 1.13.1
```

Comment: is this requirement inside a requirements.txt file? if so just do `pip install -r requirements.txt` and the exact version of each library will be installed as specified in the file

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki this is not in a format that is understandable by `pip`, nor is that possible to specify a Python version in a requirements file

Comment: Why would you knowingly install an EOL version? and I believe the installers are still available on [python.org](https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/). What issues are you facing?

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki Can pip install python like that? Not a retorical question, I really don't know the answer myself.

Comment: @JonSG It can not.

Comment: @DeepSpace I went through the link https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-3716/ This is for 3.7.16. I did not find Python 3.7

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki It is not written on the requirement file. It's written on GitHub readme.md

Comment: You can use the latest 3.7 that you can find.

Comment: @DeepSpace Can you share the link? How can I find that?

Comment: @DeepSpace I believe the link for the newer version is "https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-3717/". But where is the download link?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:**

I am able to successfully download python 3.7 on my Windows

As commented by @CrazyChucky and @Brian

**`3.7.9` is the latest 3.7 python with pre-build Windows installers**

https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-379/

3.7.17 is the latest version with security patches. It contains gzipped and XZ compresses files.

https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-3717/

[image]

Comment: 3.7.2 release candidate 1? Why? If it has to be 3.7 - which I still doubt - then you could at least use a more up-to-date version.

Comment: Sorry I don't know about release candidate 1. I was searching for the download link on python.org I found the above link.

Comment: @Goku That's the version you supplied. It's essentially a beta version of 3.7.2.

Comment: There's links for full releases of Python 3.7 on the main Windows downloads page: https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/. 3.7.17 is the latest. 3.7.9 is the last release with binary installers.

Comment: @Brian61354270, CrazyChucky  thanks guys I have edited my answer and included the latest links and removed the old link.

Answer (score 2):

If you really must use Python 3.7 (which, as you noted, has reached end-of-life), the most up-to-date version, with security patches, is [3.7.17](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-3717/).

Download either of the two files listed on that page ([gzipped](https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.7.17/Python-3.7.17.tgz) or [xz compressed](https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.7.17/Python-3.7.17.tar.xz)). They contain exactly the same source code, just compressed in two different formats. Open the archive you've downloaded, and follow the instructions in `PCBuild/readme.txt` in order to build and install Python from source.

If *at all* possible, please consider using a newer version of Python. At least just try 3.8 and see if the project you're working on functions correctly with it. Alternatively, see if you can find a more up-to-date version of whatever project you're trying to set up.

Comment: FWIW, the last 3.7 release with pre-built Windows installers is [3.7.9](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-379/).